# How to read file content and store in local variable using thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to read a file in a thread and store the data present in the file in a local variable (a variable present outside of thread, in the script). I am sending this variable to the thread as an argument. If I am not reading a file, and just accessing the variable, everything works fine. But if I am reading a file, then the variable (dictionary here) comes up empty. I am not sure why that's the case. Please let me know why this might be happening and what I can do about it. Thanks.

(I am using python 3.9.6 on Windows 10)

```py
import threading
import time
import os

def thread_function(filename: str, line_dict: dict, lock:threading.Lock):
  lock.acquire(blocking=True, timeout=5.8)
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for id,line in enumerate(f):
      line_dict['line{}'.format(id)] = line
  lock.release()
  print('[from thread] Keys in Dictionary: \n{}'.format(line_dict.keys()))

line_dict = {}
lock = threading.Lock()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  t = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=('./lines.txt', line_dict, lock))
  t.start()
  print('[from main] Keys in Dictionary: \n{}'.format(line_dict.keys()))
  t.join()
```

Comment: You want the final print statement AFTER the t.join() statement.  The dictionary isn't populated until the thread finishes.  By the way, your lock object does nothing here - the purpose of a lock is to prevent two threads from modifying the same object at the same time.  You only modify the dictionary in the second thread.

Comment: What if I have a long running thread, that needs to keep checking if file gets updated and update the dictionary accordingly. I can't wait for the thread to finish then, what can I do there?

Comment: In your example code, your secondary thread is already reading the file and changing the dictionary (which was your question).  But you can't see it, because when Thread1 hits the print statement, Thread2 hasn't read the data yet.  So you need to delay Thread1 until the data appears.  One way to do that is with .join, but a time delay will also work.  Put a call to time.sleep (with a long enough delay) into the main thread, before the print statement, and you will see the data printed.  In a real application of course Thread1 can be doing something useful instead of just sleeping.